# Converting .csv file to .arff by sub process in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following scripts as a subprocess in python: The scripts is a convertor from .csv t0 .arff.

```
import subprocess, os

for counter in range(1,10):
        cmd = ['java', '-cp', '/weka.jar', 'weka.core.converters.CSVLoader', '/CsV/file'+str(counter)+'.csv', '>', '/Arff/file'+str(counter)+'.arff']
        print (' '.join(cmd))
        subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

"cmd" works properly when I directly run it in the terminal and I can see the converted file in "/Arff/" which the location that the converted file should be.
 But , when I run the script through the subprocess I cannot see any converted file in the location. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I use "macintosh"

Comment: You're trying to redirect stdout of the subprocess. You can't do that without specifying `shell=True` or handling the pipe yourself.

Comment: It's not really an answer but on OSX a path starting with `/` means the root of the system, which is not the same as `./` which means this directory. Secondly, rather than piping the output of the command with a `>`, you might be better of using the [stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.stdout) and using Python to write that output into a file.

Comment: if your mean is: 
 subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True)
I tried, but I got an error.

Comment: Such is life. If you tell us what the error is then maybe someone could help you with it...

Comment: might need to add `-jar` to the `cmd` parameters: `java -cp .:weka.jar -jar weka.jar`, etc..

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by "stdout" that @SamuelHarmer suggested. Thank you.